# How to convert IDA Pseudo code casts to Array

Tags: ida, array

I have a pseudo code in IDA which is as such

consdering `v5= 3838385024767399985LL`

`v1 += 53 * *((char *)&v5 + i);`

In C-Friendly format this should be
`v1 += 53 * v5[i]`

Is there any way in IDA Pro to convert the above gibberish into a nicer array style value?

Comment: Provide the assembly. It will be easy to understand that if v5 is a long long or a struct/array.

Answer (score 1):

If old pseudocode looks like this

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
{
  signed int i; 
  int v5; 
  __int64 v6; 

  v6 = 5208208757389214273LL;
  v5 = 0;
  for ( i = 0; i <= 7; ++i )
    v5 += *((char *)&v6 + i);
  return 0;
}
```

Select `v6` and press Y (`Set lvar type` in right click context). Change from `__int64 v6` to `char v6[8]`;

Now it looks like

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
{
  signed int i; 
  int v5; 
  char v6[8]; 

  *(_QWORD *)v6 = 5208208757389214273LL;
  v5 = 0;
  for ( i = 0; i <= 7; ++i )
    v5 += v6[i];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should it be 8 or 10 ? (the array size) @sudhackar

Comment: `_QWORD` and __int64 are both 64bit(8 bytes)

Comment: I see. So, let's see the array has size like 10. How would the IDA show ? Would it use two variables _int64 and int?

Comment: Sometimes IDA will see these optimised array assignment as qwords, you should start at the base of the string and then set the length to what you expect, IDA will automatically merge the next qwords into the string.